# Asterisk AMI Kamailio load balancer

Tags: asterisk, kamailio

I'm trying to configure Kamailio with Asterisk to load balance.
So expectation is:

1: I have 1 Kamailio server

2: 2 Asterisk servers

3: 1 application manager server which will send AMI request to Kamailio

4: Call will be for asterisk AMI on port 5038 from my application server.

5: Kamailio should understand and route AMI request(port 5038) to Asterisk servers using same port.

Answer (score 1):

Kamailio is SIP proxy, it know nothing about AMI protocol.

Use general proxy like HAProxy or specific AMI proxy

> Manager Proxies
>
> ```
> Octopasty is a Python based multi-client/multi-server proxy for the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI)
> AACC daemon, allows large number of agents to connect to asterisk and get CTI functionality.
> AstManProxy is a Multi-Threaded Manager Proxy with support for multiple I/O formats, including XML
> Asterisk Flash Operator Panel contains a manager proxy in perl
> Asterisk Simple Manager Proxy simplified version of the proxy in Asterisk Flash Operator Panel
> Astguiclient contains a manager proxy that uses a MySQL to queue requests
> Asterisk GUI DeStar contains a Python based manager proxy
> DialApplet, Unified communications
> TclMyAst offers a proxy that maintains channel state.
> RAMI contains a built-in manager proxy in Ruby
> CommServer is a Proxy server which gives the complete user profiling and billing managment for voip services using AMI.
> (amiws) Asterisk Management Interface (AMI) to Web-socket proxy on C. Can work with multiple AMI servers via TCP/TLS.
> ```

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-manager-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

Kamailio is not a smart software (not feature based) and you can use it as a proxy or loadbalancer to dispatch calls over asterisks. For AMI side, Asterisk can talk to AMI as I know.
In kamailio, you should use dispatcher module for loadbalancing over Asterisks. In this case, Kamailio can dispatch calls with a type of algorithm that you want. Round-Robin is the best option as my experiences.